# T-SQL OPENQUERY instead of SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I have a working T-SQL `OPENQUERY` connection to a KISAM ODBC database table that returns the expected number of rows based on a where clause on a single date field for yesterday's date:

```sql
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @MyDate varchar(10)

SET @MyDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), (DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)), 120)

SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(KODBC_linked_server,''SELECT * from [table] WHERE date_column_1 = ''''' + @MyDate + ''''''')'

EXEC (@TSQL)
```

I need to expand the query to include multiple date fields in the where clause, but keep getting an error

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server...

How do I pass multiple date fields in the where clause?

Comment: *"How do I pass multiple date fields in the where clause?"* If KISAM follows the same rules as other RDBMS, with additional `AND` and `OR` boolean clauses, or an` IN`, depending on  what your goal is. Seems like the question here is about how to query a KISAM database and not how to write T-SQL.

Comment: Does this KISAM tool have it's own query tool? Because what's clouding the issue here is the usual problem with escaping single quotes.

Comment: Post the complete error - ALL of it, including the id, severity, etc. And don't abbreviate / truncate the actual error message - ellipsis (...) helps no one.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Larnu.  Yes, it is more about how to query a KISAM database.  Nick.  Not that I know of or can find.  SMor.  Here is the full error  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server" returned message "[Kerridge][KISAM ODBC Driver][KISAM]syntax error in: from [table] where (col1 = @ >>> MyDate <<< ) OR (col2 = @MyDate)".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from [table] where (col1 = @MyDate) OR (col2 = @MyDate)" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server".

Comment: Does KISAM support variables like `@MyDate`? I guess not. You'll need to find out. I guess you need to put a date literal in instead of a variable

Comment: Hi @Nick.  thank you for continuing with this.  the MyDate variable works when only the one Where clause is used, but it is surrounded by + and ' symbols, as per the working query in the original question.  I haven't yet tried putting brackets around the existing Where clause, then using OR and repeating the clause as is, but changing the column name - i'll try that now and update this message

Comment: Depending on whatever dialect KISAM uses (a manual reference would be useful), The `OR` operator could actually be `||` or something else weird like that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who commented and made suggestions.  Unfortunately, nothing is working and the customer has allowed their support with the original database developers to lapse, so I am unable to take this any further.